# Error when trying to knit R markdown: ! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character 锛?(U+FF0C) (inputenc) not set up for use with LaTeX

Tags: r, latex, r-markdown, pdflatex, xelatex

The error clearly has something to do with Latex, and I have tried my best to google and solve it, but all I got is just more errors.

The initial error:

```
! Package inputenc Error: Unicode character 锛?(U+FF0C)
(inputenc)                not set up for use with LaTeX.

Try other LaTeX engines instead (e.g., xelatex) if you are using pdflatex. See https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/latex-unicode.html
错误: LaTeX failed to compile Jan-26-in-class-code.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Jan-26-in-class-code.log for more info.
此外: Warning message:
In grepl("==> Fatal error occurred", x[i], fixed = TRUE) :
  输入的字符串1不适用于此语言环境
停止执行
```

So I tried xelatex. Then I got

```
! LaTeX Error: File `unicode-math.sty' not found.

! Emergency stop.
<read *> 

! Unfortunately, the package unicode-math could not be installed.

! Please check the log file:

! C:\Users\86188\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\2.9\miktex\log\xelatex.log

错误: LaTeX failed to compile Jan-26-in-class-code.tex. See https://yihui.org/tinytex/r/#debugging for debugging tips. See Jan-26-in-class-code.log for more info.
停止执行
```

I guess the problem is I don't have "unicode-math" installed on my computer, so I tried install.packages("unicode-math"), then I got

```
Warning in install.packages :
  package ‘unicode-math’ is not available for this version of R
```

I sincerely appreciate any instructions or suggestions. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

unicode-math is a LaTeX package and not an R package so it needs to be installed using a LateX package manager; either tlmgr if using the TeX Live distribution or using MiKTeX Console with MiKTeX (usually the main TeX distribution on Windows).

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you have a mandarin version of comma (，）instead of (,) I ran into the same problem. Really just a typo

If you want to fit it, you can use search (Ctrl+F) and type the wrong version of comma and fix that. Hope this helps!